# FPDF - How to Align Line by Line in Python

Tags: python

I am converting a text file into a PDF using FPDF library using python. When the text prints on the PDF format the first line the columns and text are not aligned as they were in my original text file. Is there anything i can do to fix this?

I have tried changing A4 to A3, Letter, A5, etc but it did not do anything. I have tried changing the width and height as well.

```
 pdf = FPDF("L", "mm", "A4")
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.set_font('arial', style='', size=10.0)
        with open(out_file, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                pdf.multi_cell(h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt=line, border=0)
                print(line)
            filename = account+'.pdf'
            pdf.output(filename, 'F')
```

Below is text version and then how it looks in PDF version.

Text File :
Notice how the columns and text are lined up somewhat on the text file.

https://flic.kr/p/2hpCfKm

PDF FILE:

https://flic.kr/p/2hpCgwB